# Username impersonates real person

Tags: support

Is this username valid?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/5400138/carly-fiorina

If not, how do i snitch?

Comment: What's the issue exactly?

Comment: Wikipedia-Link to an american republican politician by that name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carly_Fiorina If that's of any interest to anyone... though I doubt that's actually relevant.

Comment: @Joe As per the title. The user is using a real persons name and photograph for their profile. I highly doubt Carly Fiorina is posting on SO at the moment.

Comment: @Deduplicator are you sure? [This is the only link I get when I search for "American politician"](http://m2.i.pbase.com/g3/27/613727/2/56819062.HORSESASS.jpg)

Comment: @rism this means very little to me. How do you know it isn't the real person? How do you expect non-Americans to know who it is?

Comment: @Joe Common sense.

Comment: @rism or I guess you could edit your question and explain the issue you're actually reporting. Fun fact: Not everyone is American and follows American politics.

Comment: "How do I snitch"??  Dude, sleep on it for inspiration or pick "Santa Claus".

Comment: @Joe You can include me in both of those categories.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13039/is-it-ok-to-impersonate-a-public-figure

Comment: Highly relavant: [Is it ok to impersonate a public figure?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13039/is-it-ok-to-impersonate-a-public-figure)

Comment: @psubsee2003 great minds think alike...

Comment: @apaul34208 great minds think alike (would have been funnier if I had been faster)

Comment: @Joe I think she is much more famous as the former CEO of HP than for being an American politician, so I think she is more well known amongst the community on this site than a normal political candidate

Comment: @HansPassant Dude, Hate to break it to you but Santa Claus isn't real..

Comment: What is the difference between using a super model's name as opposed to a super model's image? The latter is done on Stack Overflow.... alot....

Comment: @TinyGiant Not sure about "opposed to" but in combination, I believe, don't quote me, it would be 3rd degree felony in Texas.

Comment: The fact is that it's not. I can make my display image or name whatever I please, and there is nothing that any law can (nor should be able to) do about it.

Comment: @TinyGiant 3rd paragraph http://business.time.com/2013/01/22/can-you-go-to-jail-for-impersonating-someone-online/

Comment: Big difference, Stack Exchange is not a social media site, and you would have to prove that the user was actually impersonating someone and had malicious intent. Any user exhibiting malicious intent is usually booted before too many people notice. I don't see how you could ever actually tattle-tale on someone in this manner, it would take a hell of a lot of work on your part and everyone would probably just laugh.

Comment: No, there's no difference. The article refers to "online" not "social media". And there's little burden of proof since it's the name AND photograph being used. Pretty hard to say you meant the other such and a such when you've used their photo. But either way the community doesn't care so... whatever.

Comment: Apparently [Donald Trump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5156828/donald-trump) is also on SO...

Comment: @apaul34208 Now you're just rubbing it in.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this username valid?

Yes. Why wouldn't it be? [There can be more than one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs)

> If not, how do i snitch?

You just did

Comment: So anyone can be Jeff Atwood and use his image? Interesting.

Comment: If you try to pose as another user (especially a mod), it will be dealt with. Otherwise, it's just not worth the sweat... and potential embarrassment.

Comment: We love mods more than politicians :) @Deduplicator