# What is the policy on user names that are obvious impersonators of actual persons?

Tags: discussion, users, display-names

I'm wondering what the policy/guidelines are for users registering with user names that are obviously impersonating actual persons? For example: [Hillary Clinton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6048670/hillary-clinton). Politics aside, is this something Stack Overflow is condoning?

**Edit**
From the comments, and links to other questions, apparently Stack Overflow is represented by a number of political figures:

- [Barack Obama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2159769/barack-obama)
- [Hillary Clinton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6048670/hillary-clinton)
- [Bernie Sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5593229/bernie-sanders)
- [Donald Trump](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5156828/donald-trump)
- [Carly Fiorina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5400138/carly-fiorina)

I'm sure there are more, but I'm not going to search.

We should probably just close this question since it's been asked a few different times:

- [What are the rules governing display names and avatars?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914)
- [Username impersonates real person](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307295)
- [Is it ok to impersonate a public figure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13039)
- (relatedly, on main meta) [Does Stack Exchange have a “Verified Account” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58486)

Comment: Names are usually not unique to a single person. But then there's the picture...

Comment: I wonder what [Donald Trump](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5601870/donald-trump) would say to this?

Comment: @Rizier123 Unfortunately [Barack](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2159769/barack-obama) is about to retire.

Comment: What if Hillary really needed *help understanding LINQ*? What if that is the real Hillary but we are not believing her! Damn, I am off to get an autograph bbl.

Comment: On MSE: [Is it OK to impersonate a public figure?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13039) [What are the rules governing display names and avatars?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99914)

Comment: There are hundreds of Jon Skeets

Comment: Even Donald Trump impersonates Jon Skeet.

Comment: 'GOP' - 'Grand Original Poster'

Comment: Similar question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307295/2675154

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry, Donald had to leave.

Comment: @ChrisF meh, Republicans - just can't trust them to stay around :)

Comment: Hillary seems to be distracted from campaigning by her new hobby: 11 questions in 16 days.

Comment: I don't know why they do it.  It's bad enough getting serially downvoted because you outed some homework-vamp without extra downvotes because you happen to be a Democrat:(

Comment: @ChrisF [He will never die](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5156828/donald-trump) :P (Why did he had to leave us, because of his haircut?)

Comment: Come on, folks.  Smear campaign is all a-coming.

Comment: Donald Trump is going to make Stack Overflow great again!

Comment: My user name is an impersonation of a fictional character; is that OK?

Comment: @MrLister No. Smeg-head. (Sorry, had to make up the 15-character minimum.)

Comment: @beaker Pfff, look who's talking. At least I'm human. You're a _muppet!_

Comment: Guys why can't we all just barry the hatchet and get along?

Comment: Bob Dylan asked about Python the other day. He had the picture and all. Then again, I wonder what the real Bob Dylans out there think about the fact that Robert Zimmerman stole their name.

Comment: "What's in a name?", asked Shakespeare. "This question", answered Stackoverflow.

Comment: As long as they give good answers and do not become political..... We all know what an avatar is right?

Comment: I heard the donnie's pretty good with PHP.

Comment: I could see Bernie Sanders writing very strict C++ for some reason.

Comment: I'm Hillary Clinton and I approve of this jQuery.

Comment: If either [Hillary Clinton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6048670/hillary-clinton) or [Hillary Rodham Clinton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4736592/hillary-rodham-clinton) were asking questions on SuperUser.SE or Security.SE about running a private email server, it might be believable, but c, c++, php, sql -- no.

Comment: What if a user uses image from a web designer/developer that is clearly not him?

Comment: Well, Hillary Clinton just asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301501/best-way-to-design-a-thesaurus-in-a-sql-database).

Answer (score 25):

There are a few problems with denying names.

1. Do you have proof that those people don't actually have those names?
2. While StackOverflow probably wants actual names, it is impossible to force people to use them.
3. What harm is it to anyone on the site that they use those names.

In general while it is easy to say that people should not be able to use other names, you also can't. Those people have the right to call themselves whatever they want (whether it is their legal name or just a nickname).

Hope this maybe clears up some thoughts people are having about the topic.

Comment: If any of the *actual* people with those names complain though ...

Comment: So... who is to say that is not actually what they want to be called? And even still. You can't be telling me that there is only one "Donald Trump" in the entire world (name wise)

Comment: @TrevorClarke For that specific name, I think he might actually be the only one... by now. :P

Comment: Per [mmyers' comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13127), maybe we should ask those people not to impersonate Stack Overflow users.

Comment: @RadLexus Legally you have no way of proving that those are not their real names. It's not like StackExchange enforces names anyway.. Maybe if they did enforce names THEN maybe, but until then if you have "RadLexus" as your name than someone can have "Donald Trump"... That's just my opinion.

Comment: While I agree with the premise of this answer, it's a bit misleading to say that it's impossible to force people to use their real names. Facebook does it (how well they do it is up for debate), and I bet if SE wanted to, they could do it too.

Comment: @Cypher [Related case](http://www.theguardian.com/media/2015/nov/25/man-says-he-made-up-vietnamese-name-hoax-to-fool-news-media-and-facebook). Out of any appreciation of this hoax, I think there will be people to use false identity anyway. IIRC SecondLife approach for age verification has been a fail too.

Comment: There has to be a limit to this though. I'd bet that usernames like "Joseph Stalin", "Adolf Hitler" etc wouldn't be tolerated. Then there would be the whole argument over "why this name but not this name?" Joke names like Lmao Tse-Tung etc would probably be border cases.

Comment: @samgak, we do have an [Adolf Hitler](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5187754/adolf-hitler). No sign of Joseph Stalin, though, at least for now.

Comment: I believe this answer doesn't actually address the question where "obvious impersonators" is the operative phrase. The question is not about what someone may choose to be called; the question is specific about users intentionally impersonating someone, i.e., when the impersonating name and avatar image are one in the same, then this is case of impersonating someone else. Now, if Barack, Hillary, or any of the others listed in the question are THE Barack, Hillary, et. al., then that's a story the media needs to pick up: "Presidential candidates plz sendz codz".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Welp. I guess I lost the bet with... whoever I was making it with. He must be posting from Argentina.

Comment: @samgak No. Canada.

Comment: @samgak WTF? What problem do you have of one of the most respected former leaders of Russia? (https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2019/04/16/stalins-approval-rating-among-russians-hits-record-high-poll-a65245) Even if you had your head filled with propaganda through your Western education, it is not a reason to bring it up on international site.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I didn't make any comment other than that those user names wouldn't be tolerated (I was wrong as it turned out), that's a comment on site policy not on the historical figures themselves. Why so sensitive?

Answer (score -17):

This is a valid election campaign tactic: impersonate your rival, humor him, let his well-known personality/speech be recognized in spoof posts, and then use screenshots on Facebook/Twitter.

Yes, everybody **knows** Trump/Sanders/Clinton are not Stack Overflow users. Yet, there is potential for slander.

I would ask moderators to:

- put the impersonating accounts on a watch list;
- close/delete non-technical/spoof/'funny' posts quickly, regardless of the moderator's own political views.

The potential damage to Stack Exchange in case it is perceived as a propaganda vehicle is immense. You don't want those IRS officials checking and re-checking every transaction...

Comment: Wait, if you're unfortunate enough to share your name with a presidential candidate you end up on a *watch list*? That's a terrible idea. And what does the IRS have to do with anything?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRS_targeting_controversy

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - those who share names of presidential candidates must have already gotten used to being on watch lists...

Comment: Thanks, I see what the IRS tried to do. Now we don't want to make the same mistake as them, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - SE should, ideally, stay away from politics.

Comment: I completely agree. Putting people on watch lists and closing/deleting their posts quicker than other users' does not strike me as staying away from politics, though.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - cutting propaganda is a good way to stay impartial. YMMV