# Users using other people's Twitter / GitHub on their profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, users

I've found questions dealing with [impersonation of real people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319809/what-is-the-policy-on-user-names-that-are-obvious-impersonators-of-actual-person) but these are primarily about the user names, and mostly in the context of politicians and celebrities. What about a user who sets the Twitter and GitHub links in their profile (Edit Profile -> Links) to accounts of other people?

This question was caused by a user with ~42k rep where I at first suspected their account might have been hacked, as they asked an extremely low-tier question. Further investigation of the profile showed it's probably not hacked, but "interesting" nonetheless. They use an English name with location New York, use a Twitter link of an English author/journalist with *almost* their profile name, and a GitHub profile of a somewhat well-known American dev with an entirely different name. The user itself seems to be Vietnamese which can be gleaned from the contents of their latest question (I don't care where they're from, just a data point to show they're not who their socials are pointing to).

I raised a custom flag for the user, which was declined with the comment "We don't have rules about impersonation AFAIK". That seems to be the case, but what does meta think - *should* we have rules about people using other people's Twitter / GitHub?

Note that I'm aware it would be futile to try to proactively enforce any rules about this across all users. I'm mainly thinking about situations where a clear case is found organically by someone and flagged for mod attention.

Comment: I hope this post won't start a flood of fake accounts

Comment: @Konrad I doubt that's much of a concern with the normal meta users. Maybe if the post gets featured and gets a lot of drive by traffic from main. Also, most trolls are probably busy pouring oil on the dumpster fire over at twitter at the moment ;)

Comment: While it hasn't been featured, it did become a hot meta post...

Comment: Kind of related to this question: **Is it allowed to use a profile picture of another person?**

Comment: Related on MSE: [How far should we go in disallowing 'impersonation' in profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279108/241919)

Comment: I mean, they can be Vietnamese and still be using an English name while living in New York. Linking to social accounts that are clearly two different people is a bigger indicator that the rest of their profile information is also fake. Anyway, I lost my original comment but the summary is that while linking to other folks' social media feels like an incorrect usage of the field, I'm not sure it's an actual problem outside of sincere impersonation attempts.

Comment: Can be English person living in New York using Vietnamese name to "justify" not spellchecking they posts :) Get/write a userscript that shows Q/A ratio if such accounts bother you enough...

Comment: Note: [The Acceptable Use Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) says: "_**Identity Theft and Privacy.** Users that misleadingly appropriate the identity of another person are not permitted._" Not sure how best to interpret that, but it seems simple to me. Unless there's some weird logic with the "misleadingly" part.

Comment: And we have 20 people called Donald Duck.  Shocking!  And even a Horse_with_no_name who is clearly impersonating a famous horse.

Comment: Yes, lying about the location is common (their writing style usually betrays them), probably because they think their content will be better received (there may actually be some truth to that). They ought to leave the location out or be unspecific (e.g., "Earth" or "The universe").

Comment: I have the same name as Elon Musk, but I am older than him, so actually he's the impersonator.

Comment: These links could easily be validated - why don't we do it?

Comment: Funny, there's only one Linus Torvalds. As for impersonator, it requires a *complete* profile, just a picture or name isn't enough; they need to do a complete profile that would **realistically** lead people to believe that it was the impersonated person: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174589/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279109/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174456/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99918/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74584/282094

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I went digging around the user profile you flagged (not linking due to Meta effect). Some fun facts

- The user changed their name on Oct 14
- Their previous profile data confirms they are from Asia, not New York

Which leads me to the same point of [the previous discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319851/2370483): **So what?**

There's 4 users on SO with that same name and spelling (and it's a common name). If we throw the common variant of the same, that increases to 24. I can't find anything about this user that would indicate that their having this name is hurting anything. I wasn't familiar with it and Google returns a variety of "higher profile but still relatively unknown" people. For fun, I checked some other names

| Famous Name | SO users with said name |
| --- | --- |
| Vladimir Putin | 10 |
| Donald Trump | 26 |
| Chuck Norris | 31 |
| Bill Gates | 22 |
| Steve Jobs | 44 |
| Bob Goff | 2 |
| Linus Torvalds | 1 |
| Jon Skeet | 2 |

At the risk of Meta effect, I don't think [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20010028/jon-skeet) is meant to be any sort of riff on [the famous and most prolific SO user of all time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (of *all time!*). I suspect he is probably just some guy with the same name.

### Social media links are purely a bankshot

In order for the links to have any negative effect, you need to

1. Click into their profile
2. Click the link
3. Believe the link validates who the person is

I'm not sure we can help you there if you believe everyone on the Internet is who they say they are because of a mere link anyone could have.

### TL;DR

If a user is engaged in any of the following

- Actually pretending to be another SO user (completely copying their entire profile, username, etc.)
- Trolling
- Engaging in some sort of scam based on the famous username they're using (i.e. "Email me at famousname1274623252352758903547@gmail.com!")

Those are all not allowed already. Flag such **behavior** for moderator attention.

But trying to enforce any sort of "Don't use a famous name" rule is infeasible. What if you just share the same name? What if you want to make a political statement? What if you just like their name? The reasons for doing this *are too long to list*.

And what's the harm? SO isn't a social media company where you're trying to trick me into friending you so you can access more data about me. You could jump into chat and pretend to be that person, I suppose, but that assumes you made a positive contribution to the site in the first place to get the rep to do that. [Mission accomplished?](https://xkcd.com/810/)

Comment: I'm not at all concerned with the _name_ though. I'm specifically asking about setting "your" twitter/github link to that of someone else. I agree that I can't fathom what the actual purpose would be in the specific case, especially given that they link to two unrelated people.

Comment: @l4mpi: What's the difference, really?  If someone wants to say that they're Elon Musk on Twitter, why does...that have weight?  Are they actively spamming?  Are they actively causing harm with this?  I'd imagine if someone is doing something untoward with that in their profile that it'd get handled with the rules that already exist, but I can't see actual *harm* right this instant... Could you describe the harm here?  I'm just an old meta hound but I'm struggling to connect the dots.

Comment: @Makoto As I said, in the specific case I don't see any reason for why the user is doing this. The only reason I can think of is trying to appear more american / western to someone taking a quick glance at their profile, which isn't exactly harmful. But at the same time, not knowing their rationale is putting me off - why would any reasonable user do this? And it's not an obvious fake profile like using Chuck Norris etc. TL;DR it feels fishy to me, but I'm not sure how it could become a problem, which is why I asked the question to get other people's input.

Comment: @Makoto One problem I can think of is that imporsanting a random semi-famous person (as opposed to politicians, celebrities, etc.) can make your profile look more trustworthy (e.g., "I'm this guy who's a senior developer at Microsoft and here's a link to my blog/Twitter/LinkedIn").

Comment: @l4mpi:  I mean, if you don't know their motivation, why are you assuming one?  Sure, it *could* be for nefarious things, but it might not be.  Only way to know for sure is to observe them doing fishy things.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine:  Really there's no helping that because Stack Overflow exists outside of any external verification system.  But it's also a bit of a meh point since, if one is so easily swayed by credentials instead of what the actual answer was, then they were going to be swayed by anybody, really.  Who deals with *that*?

Comment: Utterly disappointed that I'm not on the list.

Comment: 10 Users named "Vladimir Putin", yet there was an ["irrefutable" argumentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421465/politics-in-usernames) that political names in favour of russia are getting banned/censored. I'm confused right now.

Comment: @Makoto well, this started with a question of such low quality that I considered their account might have been taken over or sold (basically the equivalent of "why does this C code not run if I paste it into a bash shell?" - from a user with over 40000 rep). That already led me to believe that something is not quite right with this user.

Comment: @l4mpi:  In that case you could just flag that as suspicious unto itself.  Could be a computer that was left logged in, for all we know.  We don't *need* to leap to "omg this person is obviously doing something bad" just *yet*; I'd say let the mods investigate.

Comment: @Makoto As I already stated in the question, I did check their profile and quickly found out it's not hacked, and it's just another reminder that high rep does not mean the person has any clue what they're doing. Checking the profile however led me to the "fake" socials, which I flagged as (abbreviated) "not sure if that's impersonation or some other shady stuff, take a look please", and that came back as "no rules about impersonation", leading to the question, "well, should there be any for this case (social links)?", which brings us to right here.

Comment: @Tom The standard is we don't allow calls for violence of any kind. Political usernames and avatars are acceptable in general.

Comment: @l4mpi I made an edit right before your comment. I don't think social links (which are not prominently displayed) change the equation here. Impersonating someone is easier on SO, but there's no obvious benefits.

Comment: @Machavity I know, I wasn't the one who had made up arguments to pretend there was censorship of usernames :D

Comment: @Tom well, there were real user names that were changed which weren’t necessarily calling for violence but contained epithets about a specific nationality. Totally justified actions from the moderators, imo, but the scenarios in the question you linked to weren’t too far from reality.

Comment: I don't know why someone would use another persons' portrait, but in other places I have seen people using famous historical persons' name and portrait. I could imagine they want to indicate that they follow in their footsteps and in that case I could imagine a similar case even for living persons - explaining why we have a few "Donald Knuth" and 20+ "Alan Turing" on stackoverflow, and one DonaldDuck on meta.

Comment: There is a difference between Bill Gates and Ryan Florence for example. Nobody will expect that the user with the name Bill Gates is actually Bill Gates, but using Ryan Florence as a username and his social links and bio can trick other users.

Comment: "What if you want to make a political statement?" Putting aside my disagreement with the policy generally permitting political statements (it is off topic and provocative), I struggle to understand *what statement is being made* by representing oneself to be a specific political figure, and then asking and/or answering questions about programming.

Comment: In some extreme cases, users try to "get revenge" on someone who criticised them or their answer or who they think downvoted them. More commonly, employers would see what they can find online about job candidates. Someone sharing only someone else's name may be hard to verify as impersonation (as opposed to just having the same name as them). But having someone try to pass links to another person's profiles off as their own (or using their uniquely identifying information) could result in negative consequences for the impersonated person. That really shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @rene There are currently 6698 other users with your name. Congrats, you win! :-)

Comment: @TylerH *adds one to list. perfectly balanced.

Comment: Do companies use stack overflow when researching candidates? If yes, this opens the possibility of harming someone by creating a convincing enough fake account and asking poor questions, giving poor answers, or being a jerk. If social media links and images are such low-impact features form harm, they are probably low-impact features. Why even have them?

Comment: Thinking a little more about this and how uneasy I would be if there was an account here that linked to my LinkedIn profile and used my name…I can't help thinking that if a site allows users to link their accounts to real-world identities, they have a responsibility to authenticate their users. This, of course, is hard and probably not worth the small benefit of allowing users to provide these links.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as no other actionable suggestions have surfaced. So to summarize, simply using socials of other people is not enough reason to bother a mod, only report it if there's evidence of bad behaviour along with it.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the broader question you asked (*"users using other people's info on their profile"*), not on that specific user you mentioned:

As a person that has his real name as the username and his real image as the profile photo (I'm not on any moral high ground), I always felt a bit uncomfortable with the fact that SO (or SE sites) users can use fake names/images. But of course there's nothing one can do to enforce users providing real names/images.

Therefore, we have to be **consistent**. Not only the name/image can mean nothing, all the other fields in the profile can also be considered meaningless or fake. That applies to:

- Location
- Title
- Website link
- Twitter link or username
- GitHub link or username

I know those last three can be deceptive, but there's nothing special with them: if the username and the image can be anything the user chooses, those fields can be as well.

Comment: "But of course there's nothing one can do to enforce users providing real names/images" - excuse me? Stack Overflow can certainly ban users who use provably fake names/images. Maybe you think that's not viable or they shouldn't do so (and that may very well be the case), but that's not quite the same as being unable to do anything about it. You also didn't say WHY there's nothing we can or should do, so we can't apply the same (unspecified) reasoning consistently. It may very well be the case that the reason why we can't do anything about a fake username doesn't apply to a fake profile link.

Comment: @NotThatGuy what I read from this answer is that users are forced to use their real name/photo/detail, not even pseudonyms, similar to [a discussion on MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2574/60571). And [real-account verification has been officially declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58486/241919)

Comment: @AndrewT. Whether someone uses their real name is completely different from whether someone uses a URL to a website profile that provably uniquely points to a specific individual that isn't them.